# Question in Ch-12 Apostol's Number theory (Vol1)

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, bernoulli-polynomials

I am trying some exercises from Apostol's Introduction to Analytic number theory and I could not solve this particular problem (number 16) of textbook and need help.

[image]

I am sorry, I wouldn't be able to provide anything as attempt as I have no ideas on which result to use.

For background, I am taking number theory course this sem where bernaulli polynomials were taught and also read them from Apostol.

Kindly shed some light on this!!

Comment: odd-indexed Bernoulli numbers (besides $B_1$) are zero

Comment: Presumably, the first thing to use is whatever definition Apostol gives for the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: So, have you checked to see how Apostol defines the Bernoulli numbers?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson yes!!

Comment: And what did you find?

Comment: Come on, User, meet us halfway.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Bernaulli numbers are defined as : If |z|<2$\pi$ , then $\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_n z^n}{n!}$ . Here , $B_n$ are bernaulli numbers.

Comment: Well, that sum on the right side looks a lot like the sum in the exercise, evaluated at $z=2$. Might be the place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start recalling the Cauchy-product when multiplying two even exponential generating functions. Given
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}\qquad \text{and}\qquad B(z)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_{2l}\frac{z^{2l}}{(2l)!}
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
A(z)B(z)
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right)
\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_{2l}\frac{z^{2l}}{(2l)!}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\left(\sum_{{2k+2l=2n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{a_{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{b_{2l}}{(2l)!}\right)z^{2n}\tag{1.1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{b_{2(n-k)}}{(2(n-k))!}\right)z^{2n}\tag{1.2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}a_{2k}b_{2n-2k}\right)\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}\tag{1.3}
\end{align*}
*Comment:*

- In (1.1) we use the *[Cauchy-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)* and sort according to even powers of $z$.
- In (1.2) we replace $l$ by $l=n-k$, observing the index range of $k$ is $0\leq k\leq n$.
- In (1.3) we use the binomial coefficient $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}$. We see the product $A(z)B(z)$ is also an even exponential generating function.

Interpreting left-hand side and right-hand side of OPs relation as coefficients of even exponential generating functions,

> we obtain according to (1.1) - (1.3)
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^\infty&\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^r\frac{2^{2k}B_{2k}}{(2k)!(2r-2k+1)!}}\right)z^{2r}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{2r}{2k}\underbrace{2^{2k}B_{2k}}_{a_{2k}}
> \underbrace{\frac{1}{2r-2k+1}}_{b_{2r-2k}}\right)\frac{z^{2r}}{(2r)!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{2k}B_{2k}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2l+1}\,\frac{z^{2l}}{(2l)!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_{2k}\frac{(2z)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\,\frac{1}{z}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2l+1}}{(2l+1)!}\\
> &=\left(\frac{2z}{e^{2z}-1}+z\right)\frac{1}{z}\,\sinh z\tag{2}\\
> &=\left(\frac{2z}{e^{2z}-1}+z\right)\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}=\cosh z\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(2r)!}}z^{2r}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we recall the *[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function)* of the Bernoulli numbers
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{z}{e^z-1}&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty B_r\frac{z^r}{r!}\\
  &=1 - \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z^2}{12} - \frac{z^4}{720} + \frac{z^6}{30240}-\cdots 
  \end{align*}
  where besides the linear term $-\frac{z}{2}$ all other  terms with odd powers are zero. We therefore have
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{2z}{e^{2z}-1}&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty B_{2r}\frac{z^{2r}}{(2r)!}-\frac{2z}{2}\\
  \frac{2z}{e^{2z}-1}+z&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty B_{2r}\frac{z^{2r}}{(2r)!}
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we do some simplifications.

Comment: $ \begin{align*}
A(z)B(z)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\left(\sum_{{2k+2l=2n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{a_{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{b_{2l}}{(2l)!}\right)z^{2n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}a_{2k}b_{2n-2k}\right)\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}\tag{1}
\end{align*}$ How did in the term Right of Rhs you wrote second summation which is in k from 0 to n? Can you please explain?

Comment: The explanation that you gave for following identity is not sufficient:$\begin{align*}
\frac{2z}{e^{2z}-1}&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty B_{2r}\frac{z^{2r}}{(2r)!}-\frac{2z}{2}\\
\frac{2z}{e^{2z}-1}+z&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty B_{2r}\frac{z^{2r}}{(2r)!}
\end{align*}$, because I think if you plug 2z instead of z

Comment: in the identity $\frac {z}{e^z -1}= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}{B_r z^r} {r!}$ You will get $\frac{2z} {e^z -1} = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} B_{2r} \frac{z^{2r}} { (2r)!} $ and -2z /2 factor will not come up. I think you need to elaborate on that if that's right?

Comment: @No-One: I've added some details regarding (1). With respect to your second comment: Observe the series expansion in the comment section shows precisely *one* term with odd power, since all other Bernoulli numbers with odd index are zero. Now substitute $z$ by $2z$ in $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ and you obtain the series with even Bernoulli numbers $B_{2r}$ and just one term $-\frac{2z}{2}$ with odd power of $z$.

Comment: @episqrt I will get back to you as soon as i can. Also, Can you have a look at this question.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3883256/function-epsilons-chi-related-to-dirichlet-l-function Thanks!

Comment: @No-One: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)

Comment: Can you also have a look at the following question :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3883256/function-epsilons-chi-related-to-dirichlet-l-function  . Nobody is answering it and it has a bounty of 50 points on it.

Comment: @No-One: I'm busy at the moment. I'll look at it within the next few days.

Comment: It's absolutely fine. I am in no hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that Cauchy product is defined as

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k=\sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m\sum_{r=0}^ma_rb_{m-r}
$$

We may apply it to the left handside of what the problem states:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty z^{2r}\sum_{k=0}^r{2^{2k}B_{2k}\over(2k)![2(r-k)+1]!}
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty{(2z)^{2r}B_{2r}\over(2r)!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{z^{2n}\over(2n+1)!} \\
&=\left[{2z\over e^{2z}-1}+z\right]\cdot{e^z-e^{-z}\over2z} \\
&={e^z-e^{-z}\over e^z(e^z-e^{-z})}+{e^z-e^{-z}\over2}=\cosh z \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{z^{2r}\over(2r)!}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comparing the coefficients of the $z^{2r}$ terms yields

$$
\sum_{k=0}^r{2^{2k}B_{2k}\over(2k)!(2r+1-2k)!}={1\over(2r)!}
$$

which is exactly what the problem asks us to prove.

Comment: Can you please tell how you wrote $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} (2z)^{2r} B_{2r} / (2r)!$  =$[ 2z/{e^{2z -1} +z] $ in line 4 of your answer?

Comment: Can you please reply to my previous comment if you have some spare time?